# Full disk encryption on a dual boot system OS X/Win7 (one hard disk)

Tags: windows, macos, multi-boot, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I have a macbook pro with lion on it. I'd like to put win 7 on it and dual boot it - on the same HDD.

I'd also like to encrypt as much of it as possible and use open source encryption if possible.

I gather that it is impossible to do it on one hdd using fde.

Is it possible to separately encrypt each partition?, What are my options?

Also, what happens if I want to update one if the operating systems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)? It can encrypt entire drives, including the system drive. Updating won't really matter, since you'll only be changing the contents of the drive.