# Dual boot Windows and Linux with pre-boot authentication and encryption

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bootloader, truecrypt

Is it still possible to encrypt both Windows and Linux (in this case Ubuntu) with a tool that works on both operating systems? I'd like to have a pre-boot authentication setup, like what you used to be able to do with TrueCrypt, but since it is no longer in development, and has proven to be insecure for this method, I was wondering if a new tool had come out to do this. I know that VeraCrypt came out after TrueCrypt was discontinued, but it only has pre-boot authentication with Windows. The only reason I wouldn't run that or BitLocker beside a LUKS encrypted Ubuntu OS is because I'd like to be able to encrypt the original boot partitions, and keep the bootloader to decrypt them on a USB (like I did with TrueCrypt), so it isn't vulnerable to attack. I know this is a paranoid method, but I'd like to be able to do it if possible, and I haven't found an adequate replacement to TrueCrypt that would do all that for both operating systems.

Comment: Similar question....https://superuser.com/questions/393830/full-disk-encryption-on-a-dual-boot-system-os-x-win7-one-hard-disk?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but that method uses TrueCrypt, which I explained wouldn't work for me.